# Tensorflow OOM (Out of memory) in Semantic Segmentation DeeplabV3+ - evaluation mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am running out of memory (OOM) when running semantic-segmentation using DeepLabV3+ from [this](https://github.com/rishizek/tensorflow-deeplab-v3-plus) repository (evaluation script - **evaluate.py**) .

A strange aspect is that I have successfully trained the network, however I am
unable to evaluate. My batch size is 1, so I cannot reduce it further (solution for other users with OOM propblem).

For testing purposes I ran the evaluation on a single image and this works fine. However when I assign a folder with my complete dataset (~50 images) the problem arises again.

I suspect the problem lies in **utils/preprocessing/eval_input_fn()** method where tries to read all data and parse the into floats **lines 234, 244**

Any ideas on how to proceed are much welcome.
I also attach below the two scripts (evaluate.py, preprocessing.py) and the error I get.

*Hardware: 4xTitan Xp 12GB ---> code uses only one

## evaluate.py

```
    """Evaluate a DeepLab v3 model."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import os
import sys

import tensorflow as tf

import deeplab_model
from utils import preprocessing
from utils import dataset_util

import numpy as np
import timeit

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--image_data_dir', type=str, default='dataset/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages',
                    help='The directory containing the image data.')

parser.add_argument('--label_data_dir', type=str, default='dataset/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationClassAug',
                    help='The directory containing the ground truth label data.')

parser.add_argument('--evaluation_data_list', type=str, default='./dataset/val.txt',
                    help='Path to the file listing the evaluation images.')

parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default='./model',
                    help="Base directory for the model. "
                         "Make sure 'model_checkpoint_path' given in 'checkpoint' file matches "
                         "with checkpoint name.")

parser.add_argument('--base_architecture', type=str, default='resnet_v2_101',
                    choices=['resnet_v2_50', 'resnet_v2_101'],
                    help='The architecture of base Resnet building block.')

parser.add_argument('--output_stride', type=int, default=16,
                    choices=[8, 16],
                    help='Output stride for DeepLab v3. Currently 8 or 16 is supported.')

_NUM_CLASSES = 21


def main(unused_argv):
  # Using the Winograd non-fused algorithms provides a small performance boost.
  os.environ['TF_ENABLE_WINOGRAD_NONFUSED'] = '1'

  examples = dataset_util.read_examples_list(FLAGS.evaluation_data_list)
  image_files = [os.path.join(FLAGS.image_data_dir, filename) + '.jpg' for filename in examples]
  label_files = [os.path.join(FLAGS.label_data_dir, filename) + '.png' for filename in examples]

  features, labels = preprocessing.eval_input_fn(image_files, label_files)

  predictions = deeplab_model.deeplabv3_plus_model_fn(
      features,
      labels,
      tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,
      params={
          'output_stride': FLAGS.output_stride,
          'batch_size': 1,  # Batch size must be 1 because the images' size may differ
          'base_architecture': FLAGS.base_architecture,
          'pre_trained_model': None,
          'batch_norm_decay': None,
          'num_classes': _NUM_CLASSES,
          'freeze_batch_norm': True
      }).predictions

  # Manually load the latest checkpoint
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.model_dir)
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

    # Loop through the batches and store predictions and labels
    step = 1
    sum_cm = np.zeros((_NUM_CLASSES, _NUM_CLASSES), dtype=np.int32)
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    while True:
      try:
        preds = sess.run(predictions)
        sum_cm += preds['confusion_matrix']
        if not step % 100:
          stop = timeit.default_timer()
          tf.logging.info("current step = {} ({:.3f} sec)".format(step, stop-start))
          start = timeit.default_timer()
        step += 1
      except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break

    def compute_mean_iou(total_cm):
      """Compute the mean intersection-over-union via the confusion matrix."""
      sum_over_row = np.sum(total_cm, axis=0).astype(float)
      sum_over_col = np.sum(total_cm, axis=1).astype(float)
      cm_diag = np.diagonal(total_cm).astype(float)
      denominator = sum_over_row + sum_over_col - cm_diag

      # The mean is only computed over classes that appear in the
      # label or prediction tensor. If the denominator is 0, we need to
      # ignore the class.
      num_valid_entries = np.sum((denominator != 0).astype(float))

      # If the value of the denominator is 0, set it to 1 to avoid
      # zero division.
      denominator = np.where(
          denominator > 0,
          denominator,
          np.ones_like(denominator))

      ious = cm_diag / denominator

      print('Intersection over Union for each class:')
      for i, iou in enumerate(ious):
        print('    class {}: {:.4f}'.format(i, iou))

      # If the number of valid entries is 0 (no classes) we return 0.
      m_iou = np.where(
          num_valid_entries > 0,
          np.sum(ious) / num_valid_entries,
          0)
      m_iou = float(m_iou)
      print('mean Intersection over Union: {:.4f}'.format(float(m_iou)))

    def compute_accuracy(total_cm):
      """Compute the accuracy via the confusion matrix."""
      denominator = total_cm.sum().astype(float)
      cm_diag_sum = np.diagonal(total_cm).sum().astype(float)

      # If the number of valid entries is 0 (no classes) we return 0.
      accuracy = np.where(
          denominator > 0,
          cm_diag_sum / denominator,
          0)
      accuracy = float(accuracy)
      print('Pixel Accuracy: {:.4f}'.format(float(accuracy)))

    compute_mean_iou(sum_cm)
    compute_accuracy(sum_cm)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

## **preprocessing.py**

```
    """Utility functions for preprocessing data sets."""

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

_R_MEAN = 123.68
_G_MEAN = 116.78
_B_MEAN = 103.94

# colour map
label_colours = [(0, 0, 0),  # 0=background
                 # 1=aeroplane, 2=bicycle, 3=bird, 4=boat, 5=bottle
                 (128, 0, 0), (0, 128, 0), (128, 128, 0), (0, 0, 128), (128, 0, 128),
                 # 6=bus, 7=car, 8=cat, 9=chair, 10=cow
                 (0, 128, 128), (128, 128, 128), (64, 0, 0), (192, 0, 0), (64, 128, 0),
                 # 11=dining table, 12=dog, 13=horse, 14=motorbike, 15=person
                 (192, 128, 0), (64, 0, 128), (192, 0, 128), (64, 128, 128), (192, 128, 128),
                 # 16=potted plant, 17=sheep, 18=sofa, 19=train, 20=tv/monitor
                 (0, 64, 0), (128, 64, 0), (0, 192, 0), (128, 192, 0), (0, 64, 128)]


def decode_labels(mask, num_images=1, num_classes=21):
  """Decode batch of segmentation masks.

  Args:
    mask: result of inference after taking argmax.
    num_images: number of images to decode from the batch.
    num_classes: number of classes to predict (including background).

  Returns:
    A batch with num_images RGB images of the same size as the input.
  """
  n, h, w, c = mask.shape
  assert (n >= num_images), 'Batch size %d should be greater or equal than number of images to save %d.' \
                            % (n, num_images)
  outputs = np.zeros((num_images, h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
  for i in range(num_images):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (len(mask[i, 0]), len(mask[i])))
    pixels = img.load()
    for j_, j in enumerate(mask[i, :, :, 0]):
      for k_, k in enumerate(j):
        if k < num_classes:
          pixels[k_, j_] = label_colours[k]
    outputs[i] = np.array(img)
  return outputs


def mean_image_addition(image, means=(_R_MEAN, _G_MEAN, _B_MEAN)):
  """Adds the given means from each image channel.

  For example:
    means = [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    image = _mean_image_subtraction(image, means)

  Note that the rank of `image` must be known.

  Args:
    image: a tensor of size [height, width, C].
    means: a C-vector of values to subtract from each channel.

  Returns:
    the centered image.

  Raises:
    ValueError: If the rank of `image` is unknown, if `image` has a rank other
      than three or if the number of channels in `image` doesn't match the
      number of values in `means`.
  """
  if image.get_shape().ndims != 3:
    raise ValueError('Input must be of size [height, width, C>0]')
  num_channels = image.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
  if len(means) != num_channels:
    raise ValueError('len(means) must match the number of channels')

  channels = tf.split(axis=2, num_or_size_splits=num_channels, value=image)
  for i in range(num_channels):
    channels[i] += means[i]
  return tf.concat(axis=2, values=channels)


def mean_image_subtraction(image, means=(_R_MEAN, _G_MEAN, _B_MEAN)):
  """Subtracts the given means from each image channel.

  For example:
    means = [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    image = _mean_image_subtraction(image, means)

  Note that the rank of `image` must be known.

  Args:
    image: a tensor of size [height, width, C].
    means: a C-vector of values to subtract from each channel.

  Returns:
    the centered image.

  Raises:
    ValueError: If the rank of `image` is unknown, if `image` has a rank other
      than three or if the number of channels in `image` doesn't match the
      number of values in `means`.
  """
  if image.get_shape().ndims != 3:
    raise ValueError('Input must be of size [height, width, C>0]')
  num_channels = image.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
  if len(means) != num_channels:
    raise ValueError('len(means) must match the number of channels')

  channels = tf.split(axis=2, num_or_size_splits=num_channels, value=image)
  for i in range(num_channels):
    channels[i] -= means[i]
  return tf.concat(axis=2, values=channels)


def random_rescale_image_and_label(image, label, min_scale, max_scale):
  """Rescale an image and label with in target scale.

  Rescales an image and label within the range of target scale.

  Args:
    image: 3-D Tensor of shape `[height, width, channels]`.
    label: 3-D Tensor of shape `[height, width, 1]`.
    min_scale: Min target scale.
    max_scale: Max target scale.

  Returns:
    Cropped and/or padded image.
    If `images` was 3-D, a 3-D float Tensor of shape
    `[new_height, new_width, channels]`.
    If `labels` was 3-D, a 3-D float Tensor of shape
    `[new_height, new_width, 1]`.
  """
  if min_scale <= 0:
    raise ValueError('\'min_scale\' must be greater than 0.')
  elif max_scale <= 0:
    raise ValueError('\'max_scale\' must be greater than 0.')
  elif min_scale >= max_scale:
    raise ValueError('\'max_scale\' must be greater than \'min_scale\'.')

  shape = tf.shape(image)
  height = tf.to_float(shape[0])
  width = tf.to_float(shape[1])
  scale = tf.random_uniform(
      [], minval=min_scale, maxval=max_scale, dtype=tf.float32)
  new_height = tf.to_int32(height * scale)
  new_width = tf.to_int32(width * scale)
  image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [new_height, new_width],
                                 method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)
  # Since label classes are integers, nearest neighbor need to be used.
  label = tf.image.resize_images(label, [new_height, new_width],
                                 method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)

  return image, label


def random_crop_or_pad_image_and_label(image, label, crop_height, crop_width, ignore_label):
  """Crops and/or pads an image to a target width and height.

  Resizes an image to a target width and height by rondomly
  cropping the image or padding it evenly with zeros.

  Args:
    image: 3-D Tensor of shape `[height, width, channels]`.
    label: 3-D Tensor of shape `[height, width, 1]`.
    crop_height: The new height.
    crop_width: The new width.
    ignore_label: Label class to be ignored.

  Returns:
    Cropped and/or padded image.
    If `images` was 3-D, a 3-D float Tensor of shape
    `[new_height, new_width, channels]`.
  """
  label = label - ignore_label  # Subtract due to 0 padding.
  label = tf.to_float(label)
  image_height = tf.shape(image)[0]
  image_width = tf.shape(image)[1]
  image_and_label = tf.concat([image, label], axis=2)
  image_and_label_pad = tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box(
      image_and_label, 0, 0,
      tf.maximum(crop_height, image_height),
      tf.maximum(crop_width, image_width))
  image_and_label_crop = tf.random_crop(
      image_and_label_pad, [crop_height, crop_width, 4])

  image_crop = image_and_label_crop[:, :, :3]
  label_crop = image_and_label_crop[:, :, 3:]
  label_crop += ignore_label
  label_crop = tf.to_int32(label_crop)

  return image_crop, label_crop


def random_flip_left_right_image_and_label(image, label):
  """Randomly flip an image and label horizontally (left to right).

  Args:
    image: A 3-D tensor of shape `[height, width, channels].`
    label: A 3-D tensor of shape `[height, width, 1].`

  Returns:
    A 3-D tensor of the same type and shape as `image`.
    A 3-D tensor of the same type and shape as `label`.
  """
  uniform_random = tf.random_uniform([], 0, 1.0)
  mirror_cond = tf.less(uniform_random, .5)
  image = tf.cond(mirror_cond, lambda: tf.reverse(image, [1]), lambda: image)
  label = tf.cond(mirror_cond, lambda: tf.reverse(label, [1]), lambda: label)

  return image, label


def eval_input_fn(image_filenames, label_filenames=None, batch_size=1):
  """An input function for evaluation and inference.

  Args:
    image_filenames: The file names for the inferred images.
    label_filenames: The file names for the grand truth labels.
    batch_size: The number of samples per batch. Need to be 1
        for the images of different sizes.

  Returns:
    A tuple of images and labels.
  """
  # Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor
  def _parse_function(filename, is_label):
    if not is_label:
      image_filename, label_filename = filename, None
    else:
      image_filename, label_filename = filename

    image_string = tf.read_file(image_filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)
    image = tf.to_float(tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.uint8))
    image.set_shape([None, None, 3])

    image = mean_image_subtraction(image)

    if not is_label:
      return image
    else:
      label_string = tf.read_file(label_filename)
      label = tf.image.decode_image(label_string)
      label = tf.to_int32(tf.image.convert_image_dtype(label, dtype=tf.uint8))
      label.set_shape([None, None, 1])

      return image, label

  if label_filenames is None:
    input_filenames = image_filenames
  else:
    input_filenames = (image_filenames, label_filenames)

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_filenames)
  if label_filenames is None:
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: _parse_function(x, False))
  else:
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: _parse_function((x, y), True))
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

  if label_filenames is None:
    images = iterator.get_next()
    labels = None
  else:
    images, labels = iterator.get_next()

  return images, labels
```

## Returned Error

```
2018-06-24 15:09:19.543117: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:680] Stats: 
Limit:                 11924940391
InUse:                  5998758912
MaxInUse:               8327384064
NumAllocs:                    7641
MaxAllocSize:           4246732800

2018-06-24 15:09:19.543188: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:279] ****_******______**___________________******************************************____________________
2018-06-24 15:09:19.543229: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1318] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:199 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[576,2048,22,25] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate.py", line 149, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "evaluate.py", line 86, in main
    preds = sess.run(predictions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1296,16,17,2048] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[Node: aspp/conv_3x3_3/SpaceToBatchND = SpaceToBatchND[T=DT_FLOAT, Tblock_shape=DT_INT32, Tpaddings=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](resnet_v2_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/add-2-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer, aspp/conv_3x3_3/SpaceToBatchND/block_shape, aspp/conv_3x3_3/strided_slice_2)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[Node: confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1/_1375 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3800_...t/Switch_1", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.


Caused by op u'aspp/conv_3x3_3/SpaceToBatchND', defined at:
  File "evaluate.py", line 149, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "evaluate.py", line 71, in main
    'freeze_batch_norm': True
  File "/home/dmarmanis/deep_learning/semantic_segmentation/models/DeepLab3/deeplab/deeplab_model.py", line 172, in deeplabv3_plus_model_fn
    logits = network(features, mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/home/dmarmanis/deep_learning/semantic_segmentation/models/DeepLab3/deeplab/deeplab_model.py", line 133, in model
    encoder_output = atrous_spatial_pyramid_pooling(net, output_stride, batch_norm_decay, is_training)
  File "/home/dmarmanis/deep_learning/semantic_segmentation/models/DeepLab3/deeplab/deeplab_model.py", line 51, in atrous_spatial_pyramid_pooling
    conv_3x3_3 = layers_lib.conv2d(inputs, depth, [3, 3], stride=1, rate=atrous_rates[2], scope='conv_3x3_3')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 183, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1049, in convolution
    outputs = layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 828, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 717, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py", line 168, in call
    outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 868, in __call__
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 520, in __call__
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 503, in _with_space_to_batch_call
    input=inp, block_shape=dilation_rate, paddings=paddings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 7486, in space_to_batch_nd
    paddings=paddings, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1296,16,17,2048] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[Node: aspp/conv_3x3_3/SpaceToBatchND = SpaceToBatchND[T=DT_FLOAT, Tblock_shape=DT_INT32, Tpaddings=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](resnet_v2_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/add-2-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer, aspp/conv_3x3_3/SpaceToBatchND/block_shape, aspp/conv_3x3_3/strided_slice_2)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[Node: confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1/_1375 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3800_...t/Switch_1", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Comment: Is there anything else running on the GPU you're evaluating with (e.g. a training process)? TF will grab all available memory for a device by default, so that would quickly lead to OOM.